# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

В чём ошибка в следующем коде?

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
session_start();
include('templates/PHP/header.html');
if($_GET['action'] == 'logout') 
{
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    header('Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]');
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])) include('profile.php');
else include('templates/PHP/auth.html');
include('templates/PHP/footer.html');
```

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at W:\domains\testTask\templates\PHP\header.html:19)
>   in W:\domains\testTask\index.php on line 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя использовать header() в теле документа, вы пытаетесь создать в 1-м фаиле 2 обработчика совершенно разных событий , разделите их на logout/login.php.

а в теле документа выполните проверку на присутствие $_SESSION['login'] и отдайте нужный контент пользователю.

Обязательно проверьте подлинность сессии .

Comment: функцию header() можно объявить только 1 раз, и перед ней не должно быть html кода

Comment: почитав об этом всем, я понял, что заголовки идут перед телом, но не могу понять как так то) если получается что html кодом я перенаправляю на ?action=logout, а после уже делаю перенаправление, средствами js я понимаю, что могу тоже перенаправить, просто интересно, как на сайтах реализуют это все средствами php

Comment: Все проверки для перенаправлений осуществляются ещё перед подключением тело. А грубые методы рода js используются в редких случаях. Например если надо пользователя выкинуть с аккаунта, например когда у него чат обновляется.

Comment: @Антон Бурак  Пример страницы logout: session_start();
setcookie("auth", '', time()-60*60*24*365*10);
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');

Comment: а ссылку выйти делайте обчной ссылкой которая направляет на lougout.php

Comment: я думал, что делать отдельный php скрипт для логаута бредово, что так не делают

Comment: ну я понял все, спасибо, использую один из вариантов

Comment: Вы можете и в 1-ом файле сделать, это не проблема, но эти условия должны быть перед началом тэга. просто в таком случее вам придется опять повторить проверку что бы отдать контент гостя или пользователя